# is there a way to create teradata volatile table and remove it after session using Spring data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, teradata

I try to create dynamically volatile table with Spring data, and drop it on the exit of program, 
is there a way to do it ?

Comment: It's dropped when the session ends automatically.

Comment: so i have just to create it using spring repository !

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't read closely enough.  I've never tried to create a volatile table with Spring, Hibernate, or anything like that.